# Table cell colouring

Tags: tables, color

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  danish,
  landscape
]{article}


\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  a3paper,
  hmargin = 0cm,
  vmargin = 4cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{
  ragged2e,
  array
}
\usepackage[
  table
]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xfp}


\def\mlr{2.5}
\newcommand*\mc[2]{\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\raisebox{\fpeval{#1*\mlr}ex}{\textbf{#2}}}}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{\raisebox{\fpeval{-5/9*\mlr}ex}{#1}}
\newcommand*\tid[1]{\saenk{#1}}
\definecolor{MB}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{MAT}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\definecolor{F/K}{rgb}{0.74, 0.2, 0.64}
\definecolor{GEO}{rgb}{0.82, 0.41, 0.12}
\definecolor{BIO}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.24}
\definecolor{HIS}{rgb}{1.0, 0.96, 0.0}
\definecolor{SAM}{rgb}{1.0, 0.31, 0.0}
\definecolor{ENG}{rgb}{0.01, 0.28, 1.0}
\definecolor{TYS}{rgb}{0.6, 0.8, 0.2}
\definecolor{DAN}{rgb}{0.93, 0.11, 0.14}
\definecolor{IDR}{rgb}{0.33, 0.41, 0.47}
\definecolor{KRI}{rgb}{0.93, 0.79, 0.69}
\definecolor{Valgfag}{rgb}{0.52, 0.73, 0.4}
\definecolor{STU}{rgb}{1, 1, 1}
\newcommand*\laerer[2]{\cellcolor{#2}\saenk{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand*\lokale[2]{\cellcolor{#2}\saenk{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\newcommand*\fag[1]{\cellcolor{#1}\saenk{\textsf{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\LARGE
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{
        |>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{6.51cm}
   *{5}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{1.48cm}
         >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{1.70cm}
         >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{0.88cm}}|
 }
  \hline
  {\bfseries\backslashbox{Tidsrum}{Ugedag}}
   & \mc{0.3}{Mandag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Tirsdag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Onsdag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Torsdag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Fredag}  \\
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{8:10\,--\,8:25}
   & \laerer{AJ}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB}
   & \laerer{LL}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{HL}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB}
   & \laerer{AJ}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{8:25\,--\,9:10}
   & \laerer{AJ}{SAM}  & \fag{SAM} & \lokale{25}{SAM}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{AJ}{HIS}  & \fag{HIS} & \lokale{25}{HIS} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{9:10\,--\,9:55}
   & \laerer{AJ}{SAM}  & \fag{SAM} & \lokale{25}{SAM}
   & \laerer{LL}{ENG}  & \fag{ENG} & \lokale{25}{ENG}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{CJ}{TYS}  & \fag{TYS} & \lokale{25}{TYS} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
                       \tid{10:25\,--\,11:10}
   & \laerer{HH}{IDR}  & \fag{IDR} & \lokale{hal}{IDR}
   & \laerer{LL}{STU}  & \fag{STU} & \lokale{25}{STU}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{MAS}{F/K} & \fag{F/K} & \lokale{fys}{F/K}
   & \laerer{MAS}{GEO} & \fag{GEO} & \lokale{25}{GEO} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
                       \tid{11:10\,--\,11:55}
   & \laerer{HH}{IDR}  & \fag{IDR} & \lokale{hal}{IDR}
   & \laerer{CJ}{TYS}  & \fag{TYS} & \lokale{25}{TYS}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{MAS}{F/K} & \fag{F/K} & \lokale{fys}{F/K}
   & \laerer{MAS}{GEO} & \fag{GEO} & \lokale{25}{GEO} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
                       \tid{12:40\,--\,13:25}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{LL}{ENG}  & \fag{ENG} & \lokale{25}{ENG}
   & \laerer{HL}{STU}  & \fag{STU} & \lokale{25}{STU}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
                       \tid{13:25\,--\,14:10}
   & \laerer{MIT}{BIO} & \fag{BIO} & \lokale{bio}{BIO}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{AJ}{HIS}  & \fag{HIS} & \lokale{25}{HIS}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT}
   & \laerer{LL}{ENG}  & \fag{ENG} & \lokale{25}{ENG} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
                       \tid{14:25\,--\,15:10}
   & \laerer{MIT}{BIO} & \fag{BIO} & \lokale{bio}{BIO}
   & \laerer{LL}{KRI}  & \fag{KRI} & \lokale{25}{KRI}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{CJ}{TYS}  & \fag{TYS} & \lokale{25}{TYS}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen, there are tiny non-coloured vertical stripes between the cells.

How do I get rid of these spaces?

Comment: a problem with the viewer! A color box can have any width, but the screen can show only multiples of the dot width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually not a good idea to mix-and-mismatch visual metaphores: If the table doesn't use colors, feel free to use horizontal and (if it really has to be so) vertical rules. Conversely, if you use colors to set off table cells, there's really no benefit from using horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,danish,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a3paper,hmargin = 0cm, vmargin = 4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%%\usepackage{diagbox} % no longer needed
\usepackage{ragged2e,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new


\def\mlr{2.5}
\newcommand*\mc[2]{\multicolumn{3}{c}{%
   \raisebox{\fpeval{#1*\mlr}ex}{\textbf{#2}}}}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{%
   \raisebox{\fpeval{-5/9*\mlr}ex}{#1}}
\newcommand*\tid[1]{\saenk{#1}}
\definecolor{MB}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{MAT}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\definecolor{F/K}{rgb}{0.74, 0.2, 0.64}
\definecolor{GEO}{rgb}{0.82, 0.41, 0.12}
\definecolor{BIO}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.24}
\definecolor{HIS}{rgb}{1.0, 0.96, 0.0}
\definecolor{SAM}{rgb}{1.0, 0.31, 0.0}
\definecolor{ENG}{rgb}{0.01, 0.28, 1.0}
\definecolor{TYS}{rgb}{0.6, 0.8, 0.2}
\definecolor{DAN}{rgb}{0.93, 0.11, 0.14}
\definecolor{IDR}{rgb}{0.33, 0.41, 0.47}
\definecolor{KRI}{rgb}{0.93, 0.79, 0.69}
\definecolor{Valgfag}{rgb}{0.52, 0.73, 0.4}
\definecolor{STU}{rgb}{1, 1, 1}
\newcommand*\laerer[2]{\cellcolor{#2}\saenk{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand*\lokale[2]{\cellcolor{#2}\saenk{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\newcommand*\fag[1]{\cellcolor{#1}\saenk{\textsf{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{
        l
   *{5}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{1.48cm}
        >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{1.70cm}
        >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{0.88cm}}
 }
   \toprule
   \addlinespace
   \textbf{Tidsrum} & 
   \multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Ugedag}}\\
   \cmidrule{2-16}
   \addlinespace
   & \mc{0.3}{Mandag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Tirsdag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Onsdag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Torsdag}
   & \mc{0.3}{Fredag}  \\

   \hphantom{1}\tid{8:10\,--\,\hphantom{1}8:25}
   & \laerer{AJ}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB}
   & \laerer{LL}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{HL}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB}
   & \laerer{AJ}{MB}  & \fag{MB}  & \lokale{25}{MB} \\[\mlr ex]

   \hphantom{1}\tid{8:25\,--\,\hphantom{1}9:10}
   & \laerer{AJ}{SAM}  & \fag{SAM} & \lokale{25}{SAM}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{AJ}{HIS}  & \fag{HIS} & \lokale{25}{HIS} \\[\mlr ex]

   \hphantom{1}\tid{9:10\,--\,\hphantom{1}9:55}
   & \laerer{AJ}{SAM}  & \fag{SAM} & \lokale{25}{SAM}
   & \laerer{LL}{ENG}  & \fag{ENG} & \lokale{25}{ENG}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{CJ}{TYS}  & \fag{TYS} & \lokale{25}{TYS} \\[\mlr ex]

   \tid{10:25\,--\,11:10}
   & \laerer{HH}{IDR}  & \fag{IDR} & \lokale{hal}{IDR}
   & \laerer{LL}{STU}  & \fag{STU} & \lokale{25}{STU}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{MAS}{F/K} & \fag{F/K} & \lokale{fys}{F/K}
   & \laerer{MAS}{GEO} & \fag{GEO} & \lokale{25}{GEO} \\[\mlr ex]

   \tid{11:10\,--\,11:55}
   & \laerer{HH}{IDR}  & \fag{IDR} & \lokale{hal}{IDR}
   & \laerer{CJ}{TYS}  & \fag{TYS} & \lokale{25}{TYS}
   & \mc{0}{\fag{Valgfag}}
   & \laerer{MAS}{F/K} & \fag{F/K} & \lokale{fys}{F/K}
   & \laerer{MAS}{GEO} & \fag{GEO} & \lokale{25}{GEO} \\[\mlr ex]

   \tid{12:40\,--\,13:25}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{LL}{ENG}  & \fag{ENG} & \lokale{25}{ENG}
   & \laerer{HL}{STU}  & \fag{STU} & \lokale{25}{STU}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT} \\[\mlr ex]

   \tid{13:25\,--\,14:10}
   & \laerer{MIT}{BIO} & \fag{BIO} & \lokale{bio}{BIO}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{AJ}{HIS}  & \fag{HIS} & \lokale{25}{HIS}
   & \laerer{LL}{MAT}  & \fag{MAT} & \lokale{25}{MAT}
   & \laerer{LL}{ENG}  & \fag{ENG} & \lokale{25}{ENG} \\[\mlr ex]

   \tid{14:25\,--\,15:10}
   & \laerer{MIT}{BIO} & \fag{BIO} & \lokale{bio}{BIO}
   & \laerer{LL}{KRI}  & \fag{KRI} & \lokale{25}{KRI}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN}
   & \laerer{CJ}{TYS}  & \fag{TYS} & \lokale{25}{TYS}
   & \laerer{HL}{DAN}  & \fag{DAN} & \lokale{25}{DAN} \\[\mlr ex]
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```